# Implementing deprecated class GTMURLBuilder in SWIFT, GoogleToolboxForMac

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-toolbox-for-mac

Tried to install Firebase services into iOS project. It seems like all goes normally. But there is an issue:

> GTMURLBuilder.m:26:17: Implementing deprecated class

It is a class ob Objective-C library made by Google. What can I do to fix this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deprecated class issue is being tracked in a GoogleToolboxForMac [GitHub issue](https://github.com/google/google-toolbox-for-mac/issues/162).

The next release of FirebaseAuth will remove its dependency on GoogleToolboxForMac. See [this PR](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/1175) for more details.